# Are user interface settings questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, topics

I was about to ask how to get the default user interface in Logic Pro X, after I closed the project window by accident, leaving only the settings for the virtual instrument in one track open.

Are those kind of questions on topic?

i.e. user interface settings in a tool for music composition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use of music software in general is on topic.  We can't really expect you to be able to use it for making music if the interface is messed up!